# Can this code be rewritten to an async function?

Tags: javascript, css, async-await

I need an element that returns a **promise** when the transition is done. Code below works fine, however, I wonder if this code can be rewritten in complete **async/await** syntax.

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const animate = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    box.classList.add("animate");
    box.addEventListener("transitionend", () => resolve());
  });

box.addEventListener(
  "click",
  async() => {
    await animate();
    console.log("done animating!");
  }, {
    once: true
  }
);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 3s linear;
}

.box.animate {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Transitions don't produce promises, to my knowledge, so you cannot natively `await` them. What you have right now seems correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` and `await` are tools to *manage* existing promises.

They replace using `then()` (and replace `catch()` with a regular `try/catch`).

They can't convert an API that uses callbacks to one that returns a promise. You still need to use the Promise constructor for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm a little confused because I thought async and await would be sugar syntax for Promises and can replace them all... (I prefer async/await because they are much easier to write and read) I still don't really understand when we should use then() and when we should use await, or, just use callbacks. Are there any good explanations for this?

Comment: "But I'm a little confused because I thought async and await would be sugar syntax for Promises and can replace them all." — No, see the first paragraph of this answer.

Comment: "I still don't really understand when we should use then() and when we should use await," — See the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: "or, just use callbacks" — See the third paragraph of this answer.